# Neo4J how to dump from webadmin

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

Help me please to create dump file from Neo4j v 2.2.3 localhost:7474/webadmin page. Looks like [dump command](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.3/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_cypher_statement_results) doesn't know how to out cypher dump to file, instead prints everything to browser console. That's problem for me since I have about 100000 entities to dump.

*How can I out dump command output to file?*

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `neo4j-shell` with the `-c` argument to execute a single command and then exit:

```
neo4j-shell -c "dump"
```

To redirect this output to a file use `> somefile.cypher`. So for example:

```
neo4j-shell -c "dump" > export.cypher
```

*Edit*

Just realized you are asking specifically how to do this from webadmin, my answer above is only relevant when running `neo4j-shell` from the command line. You can also run `neo4j-shell` remotely if you don't have access to shell on the machine.